Can I still get detected/banned by game anti-cheats if I'm running AutoHotKey script for personal use when no games are running?
I love AHK (AutoHotKey) scripts for my work (not related to games at all). But there are some complains that game anti-cheats don't like it. So I fear using it.
I have written some AHK scripts that I intend only to use for my work and not for games. And I have added some logic in it that basically tells the AHK script to quit itself whenever Steam process is running. I used a 500 ms (milliseconds) timer logic. After every 500 ms, it checks if Steam process is running or not. If running, AHK quits itself.
I added this code to eliminate the risk of getting banned in games for running this script, because I've heard some rare cases where people got banned when running AHK along with game. With this code, I can't use my AHK script when Steam is running. So the script would never be running when I launch a game from steam (unless I automate Steam and game to run one after one within less than a second).
However there could still be some milliseconds between every checks where both Steam and Script could be running parallelly (assuming I'm not quick enough to launch a game too in those moments). For example, you launch Steam and AHK script is already active. The script won't instantly quit itself. It will only quit itself when next 500 ms have passed. And I've heard some anti-cheats are always active no matter you're playing game or not.
So I'm wondering if I can get banned (or detected) because of those moments?
I'm primarily concerned about two anti-cheats:

CS2's VAC
GTA's BattleEye


Getting banned on CS2? You are joking right?

@Wimanicesir joking about GTA V also lol

VAC, no. BE, probably.
VAC only checks during runtime for memory modification, so simply having it installed on your machine would not be grounds for a ban. You could likely even have it running for something else in the background and nit get banned, as long as the scripts in use don't touch CS libraries or binaries.
BattleEye on the other hand checks for the presence of common programs and apps used to cheat, including AutoHotKey, during launch. Even if the programs are not running, their presence alone is likely enough to draw a kick/ban.
For other engines, it would similarly depend on what is being looked for; if they're monitoring binaries, you're probably fine. All that said, you may want to consider having AHK and all its files on detachable media if you're concerned; then you can know for certain it won't cause issues while it's unplugged.

Just now I received a similar response from Rockstar about BattleEye. While they didn't mention AHK itself, they simply said don't run any cheats or plugin as you could get suspended/banned. The reply was short. Isn't it sad you can't use a certain app because BattleEye doesn't like it?

It is a little over the top to ding users for merely having it installed; if those programs were activated during runtime that would be understandable. As mentioned above, you might consider putting the AHK stuff on removable media and be sure that all is well.

Regarding BattlEye on Rockstar Games, I received following responses from Rockstar Support:

We understand your query regarding the game. BattlEye only needs to be
active during online play sessions, such as when playing GTA Online.
Depending on your platform (Rockstar Games Launcher, Epic, Steam), you
can change the setting or launch option to disable BattlEye for Story
Mode.


We would like to inform you that if you are using scripting
applications like AutoHotKey, you will need to make sure that BattlEye
is disabled and Rockstar Games Launcher is closed, in this case, you
should not be banned.
You will only get banned if you use any mods or cheat applications for
playing GTA Online on their PC.


BattlEye should by default disabled if you're not running the
launchers.
Rest assured that it can only detect such app when the game is
launched. You may freely open your preferred app, just make sure that
no Rockstar games are launched while it's running to avoid any issues.

However, I'm not sure how trustworthy this information is, but I'd guess an ideal anti-cheat should be responsible like this.
